# how to configure prettier to close the script tag with `/>` instead of adding `</script>`

Tags: svelte, prettier

I have this svelte code:

```html
<script src="..." on:load={() => console.log('!')} />
```

which prettier rewrites as

```html
<script src="..." on:load={() => console.log('!')} /></script>
```

Is there a way to tell prettier to leave those cases untouched?

Comment: If you want something that can be configured, don't use prettier 

Comment: In vs code, prettier don't format html code. vscode has built-in `vscode.html-language-features`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I'm using the `pnpm run format` command that comes with svelte-kit, which also runs on a qa github action